# Identify significant deviations (gaps) of points in a 2-D distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

Consider an $X_i$, $Y_i$ distribution of points in a 2D plane. How can one assess if a given region in this 2D plane has a significant lack of points when comparing with the rest through a non-parametric test, without making any assumption on the underlying (unknown) distribution?

I would be tempted to mirror the distribution against different axes, but I'm sure if I try enough axes I'll end up finding a "significant" difference between the two sides. I'm afraid this just means I'll be affected by multiple hypothesis testing in a way I do not know how to correct for.

Comment: I do not see how you could possibly do this without making some assumptions about the distribution, for then *any* point configuration is consistent with a likely realization from some 2D distribution and, relative to it, does not "lack" any points in any region. At a minimum you must make some assumptions about homogeneity or stationarity.  What is the practical problem you are really trying to solve?

Comment: When I plotted two variables that are not expected to be correlated, a cloud of points appeared with a quadrant  (the upper right, but it does not matter) being practically devoid of points. The practical question is how to test if this "lack of points" is significant, but I would be interested about learning a bit more about the (most difficult) general question.